# Restricted join operation on the simplicial complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

Let $A$ and $B$ be two simplicial complexes (or CW-complexes) containing a common subcomplex C. 
Assume that C is contractible in both A and B.

Is it true that the space obtained gluing A and B over C homotopy equivalent to $$A \vee B \vee \Sigma C$$
where $\Sigma C$ is the suspension of C ?

Do you have any idea about that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems false. Suppose that $A$, $B$, and $C$ are all the same triangle (i.e., 3 vertices, 3 edges). Then so is the glue-up space, $X$. But $\Sigma C$ is a topological 2-sphere, so it has nontrivial second homology, while $X$ does not.

To make the example less trivial, you can take $A$ and $B$ to be $C \times I$, where $C \times \{1\}$ is the embedding of $C$ in $A$, and $C \times \{0\}$ is the embedding of $C$ in $B$, so that the space $X$ just looks like $C \times [0, 2]$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You are right. But, can we say that this claim is valid when each of A,B and C  are homopty equivalent to any sphere ? I expect that it is true.

Comment: In my first example, all three of $A$, $B$, and $C$ are (hollow) triangles, hence homotopy equivalent to $S^1$. So...no.

Comment: I think, we're missing an important point. By assuming, C must be contractible in both A and B. But, this requirement doesn't satisfiy for your example. Or, I couldn't understand.